# srlua - "Cannot find liblua.dll"

Tags: lua

I'm trying to make a standalone program - an executable for windows to be precise - out of my .lua file that works perfectly well running on SciTE (included with lua for Windows on github). I've downloaded [this](https://github.com/LuaDist/srlua/releases/tag/5.1-Windows-x86), and used the command `glue srlua.exe hi.lua hi.exe`. It gives me the executable `hi.exe` as it should, but running the program gives me an error, something along the lines of `Cannot run the code, because we can't find the liblua.dll object. Re-installation may solve this.`

I'm new to this, and it's first time I'm trying to make `.exe` out of my `.lua`. I wanted to find the `.dll`, but it's nowhere to be found, either in [Lua for Windows](https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows/releases/tag/v5.1.5-52) nor [Lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua/releases/tag/5.1.5).

Any help will be very appreciated.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

All-right, full day later found a solution, posting it here in case anybody finds it usefull:
Download [this](http://luadist.org/). I dunno how up-to-date is it, but it's got a crapton of useful executables and libraries, including the one i was looking for.